# Badge proposal: posts that are linked to often

Tags: discussion, feature-request, badges, badge-request, linked-questions

It occurred to me that incoming links to posts may be a solid quality and/or relevance criterion. Hence, I propose a (set of) badge(s) should be added to highlight posts that are linked to more often than usual.

Similar to other badges, there can be three levels with progressively larger numbers, creating sets of bronze, silver and gold.

There are different types of links to consider:

- Linked from a duplicate (applies only to questions).
- Linked from a post on the same SE site.
- Linked from a comment on the same SE site.
- Linked from a post on any SE site.
- Linked from a comment on any SE site.
- Linked anywhere on the internet.

The the last is easy to game and already represented by the Announcer/Booster/Publicist trio, I think we can savely disregard it.

As for the others, I think one can reasonably draw the line at any point, or even create different badges. A question with many duplicates may have very different qualities from one that is mentioned in many different contexts.

Even though I'm more interested in the principle, here are some concrete proposals (don't give me crap for the names, and the numbers certainly require tuning):

- Foresight/Prescience/Oracle: question has 5/50/200 duplicates
- Handout/Article/Textbook: post linked from 20/100/500 posts on the same site
- Connective/Interdisciplinary/Fundamental: post linked from 2/5/10 different SE sites

Possible reason against: There are already badges for "good" posts. -- 
Why, yes, several in fact: there are badges for views, votes, and favorites. None of these capture how relevant a post is to other posts, and can one more hurt?

Answer (score 6):

I don't think we should encourage people to post or create links for the sake of it, which is what this proposal might encourage.

It would tend to encourage posting of duplicate questions, which we don't want. We want people to search first before posting a duplicate question.

Closing as duplicates can be somewhat subjective, and I could see people closing questions as duplicates for the wrong reasons if this was in place. Or not adding the best question(s) as duplicates.

Interesting idea overall, but I don't think it accomplishes anything in terms of encouraging a good behaviour on the site.

Comment: Agree. A good idea but getting badges indirectly due to duplicates isn't a great idea I don't think. But general linking in answers may be something.

Comment: Well, the most obvious gaming can be dealth with quite easily: make only links in *other people's* posts count. Aside from that, I'd say the usual correctives (i.e. community moderation) apply to your concerns. If the worst that happens is that people add links to relevant (!) other posts, I'd count that as a win for the site.